# gtkinspector in Linux Mint Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, gtk3

How can i install and run gtkinspector in Linux Mint Cinnamon?

This solution not working: https://askubuntu.com/questions/706629/how-to-activate-keybindings-for-gtkinspector

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true
```

`gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true` returned: `No such schema "org.gtk.Settings.Debug"`

of course keyboard shortcuts don't work.

Comment: yes, thank you. Now we know that you installed those packages and it still didn't work. Try opening `dconf-editor` and searching for `inspector`. Does it find anything?

Comment: Nothing found in `dconf-editor`.

Comment: Strange. I can confirm I have the `org.gtk.Settings.Debug` on my Arch (also running Cinnamon). Did both of the `sudo` commands you show run correctly? No errors?

Comment: Absolutely no errors.

Comment: But still not working!